# Internet connection drops on ubuntu 14.04 (TP-Link TLWN821N v4 )

Tags: 14.04, realtek

I am a new linux user. 
I have recently experienced many problems with my wireless usb adaptar (realtek 8192cu); I succeeded solving them using ubuntu 13.04, however ubuntu 14.04 is much more presistent; after a week and half of searchings, I am simply lost.

The official driver http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=48&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#RTL8192CU does not officialy support kernel 3.13, but only up to 3.9.

I implemented a brilliant solution detailed at this page (https://code.google.com/p/realtek-8188cus-wireless-drivers-3444749-ubuntu-1304/issues/detail?id=12), but as noted, it doesn't work for 14.04.

While it is true that the problem is marked as solved in ubuntu wireless network adaptars section, as noted, the solutions do not work in 14.04.

I'd like to note that there is huge difference between WN821N v1,2,3 and v4 - the latter is constructed on realtek chipests, while others are made by Atheros, so, even though there are solutions for other versions, I couldn't find (after more than week of searching, even in askubuntu.com) after more than week of searchings any working solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issues with the 8192cu until I installed the dkms driver via https://github.com/vincent-t/rt8192cu_dkms

Now the connection is fast and stable.